# Real analytic function must be identically zero on $(-R, R)$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Let $g(x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_nx^n$ converge on $(-R, R)$ and assume $(x_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers that converges to $0$, with $x_n\ne 0$. If $g(x_n)=0$ for all $n$, prove that $g(x)$ must be identically zero on $(-R, R)$.

Overall, I'm not sure how to approach this one. I've tried to apply Abel's Theorem, which states that if a power series converges at some $R>0$ then it converges uniformly on $[0,R]$ (and analogously for $-R$). This seems useful for the problem, but I haven't gotten anywhere with it. Is there a way to use it here? Or is there a more direct way?

Comment: How does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_nx_n$ depend on $x$?

Comment: This is very confusing as stated; kindly correct any typos.  For instance, by $x_n$ do you mean $x^n$?  By $(x_n) \to 0,$ do you mean $(b_n) \to 0$?  And what is the definition of $g_n$?

Comment: @JesseMadnick Fixed them, one of the errors was in the text this problem came from. Didn't notice it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want $b_n$ to be both the coefficients of the power series and the sequence that goes to $0$?

Comment: If the coefficients $b_n\neq 0$ (in fact if *any* $b_n\neq 0$), then $g(x)$ is definitely not identically zero on $(-R,R)$. Something isn't right here. I think the hint is probably in Henning Malcolm's comment. This would be a true statement if the sequence that goes to zero and on which $g$ evaluates to zero were different from the coefficients in the power series.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith: the claim is still true in its current form, just vacuously so.

Comment: @HenningMakholm - fair point.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith. Does the problem make sense now?

Comment: @CuriousKid7: To clarify, you mean something like "let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $(x_n) \to 0$ and $x_n \neq 0$," is that right?  This should probably be made explicit: it's difficult to provide a correct answer when it's not clear what the problem statement is.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Changed it. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @CuriousKid7 - yes.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is some non-zero $b_n$ and consider $p=\min\{n\geq 0\;, b_n\neq0\}$.

Then $g(x)=b_px^p + o(x^p)$, hence $\dfrac{g(x)}{x^p}$ converges to $b_p\neq 0$ when $x$ goes to $0$.

Therefore, there is a neighborhood of $0$ where $\dfrac{g(x)}{x^p}>0$ or $\dfrac{g(x)}{x^p}<0$. This contradicts $g(x_n)=0$ and $x_n\to 0$.

Thus, all the $b_n$ are $0$ and $f=0$.

Comment: What does $o(x^p)$ stand for?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: You say $b_p>0$. But you define $p$ to be the smallest index so that $b_p=0$. Right?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 There were some typos, I'm sorry